# Returned variable from service not updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am following this style to write my angular code:

https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide

Basically it says to do this with your services:

```
/* recommended */
function dataService() {
    var someValue = '';
    var service = {
        someValue: someValue,
        validate: validate
    };
    return service;

    function validate() {
        /* */
    };
}
```

Which is grate until I change the someValue variable at some point.  Say I have this instead:

```
/* recommended */
function dataService() {
    var someValue = null;
    var service = {
        someValue: someValue,
        validate: validate
    };
    return service;

    function validate() {
        // do some stuff, then set someValue
        someValue = 'validated';
    };
}
```

If I make a call to dataService.validate(); I see that it sets the someValue variable.  However after that I call I try:

```
dataService.someValue
```

I get null back.

I feel like this should work just fine.  Am I going crazy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dataService.someValue` is null because you initialized `service` with `someValue = null`.

When you changed `someValue` in *`validate`* function, you didn't update the instance of `service`.

**you can try update it directly:**

```
function dataService() {
    var service = {
        someValue: null,
        validate: validate
    };
    return service;

    function validate() {
        // do some stuff, then set someValue
        service.someValue = 'validated';
    };

}
```

**or pass through a getter function:**

```
function dataService() {
    var someValue = null;
    var service = {
        getSomeValue: getSomeValue,
        validate: validate
    };
    return service;

    function validate() {
        // do some stuff, then set someValue
        someValue = 'validated';
    };

    function getSomeValue()
    {
        return someValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes a lot more sense now.